# Concatenate rows of same record to one row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, concatenation

Hello I need to include all the assignments of an employee in the same row.  Some of the employees have 1 assignment and some have 3 or more.  This is to go into a sproc and bring back all the assignments that are under that record.

Example of record in database w/ 3 records:
John doe - assign1
John doe - assign2
John doe - assign3

Desired Result:
3, assign1, assign2, assign3

Example of record in database w/ 1 record:
John doe - assign1

Desired Result:
1, assign1

This is what I have so far but can't get it to work.

```
    SELECT cast(count(*) as varchar(10))+', ' + min([Assign1])+', '+
max([Assign1]), max([Assign1])
From assignment
where year = '2012'
and first_name = 'firstname'
and last_name = 'lastname'
```

Here is the dumb downed Table structure:

```
Create INTO [database].[dbo].[assignment]
           ([employee_key]
           ,[last_name]
           ,[first_name]
           ,[assignment_code]
           ,[assignment_desc] )
```

Comment: what rdbms are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using sql server 2008

Comment: could you give us the table/tables structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look into using the `STUFF` command.  This could be optimized if you have an ID column (need your table schema), but given your above code, something like this:

```
Select cast(count(*) as varchar) + ', ' +
   stuff((select  ', '+A2.Assign1
         from Assignment A2
         where year = '2012'
             and first_name = 'john'
             and last_name = 'doe'
         for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '')
FROM Assignment A1
WHERE year = '2012'
   and first_name = 'john'
   and last_name = 'doe'
```

And the [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2dd19/3).

Here is without hard coding the WHERE clause twice:

```
Select count(*), 
   stuff((select  ', '+A2.Assign1
         from Assignment A2
         where A2.Year = A1.Year and 
            A2.First_Name = A1.First_Name and 
            A2.Last_Name = A1.Last_Name
         for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '')
FROM Assignment A1
WHERE year = '2012'
    and first_name = 'john'
    and last_name = 'doe'
GROUP BY year, first_name, last_name
```

Good luck.

Comment: It is not `stuff` that does the string concatenation it is `for xml`. In this case `stuff` is used to remove the extra comma and space from the beginning of the concatenated value. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14374392/569436) is a version that does not use `stuff` and still works just fine.

Comment: Thanks @MikaelEriksson for the clarification.  Old habits stick with me -- always seem to use the 2 commands together.  Appreciate the clarification.

Comment: Never used stuff actually.  Thanks for both of your quick responses.  I was able to produce the correct results using sgeddes first response but the count is brought back in a different column, how would I include that in the concatenation with the rest of the results under one column.

Comment: Cast the count and append the cols -- I'll edit my answer, but here is the updated Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2dd19/8