# How can I apply STUFF() to comma seperate this

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I read this: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/09/14/sql-server-grouping-by-multiple-columns-to-single-column-as-a-string/

And I can apply this to one of my queries:

```
SELECT t.TicketID, STUFF(
(SELECT ',' + tt.Tag
FROM TicketTag tt
WHERE tt.TicketID = t.TicketID
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS CSV
FROM Ticket AS t
GROUP BY t.TicketID
GO
```

This results in something like the following:

```
TicketID  CSV
1         tsql, sqlserver, c++
2         hi, bye, no
```

Now this worked because I was able to directly join to one table...
Now I want to apply `STUFF()` again to display a TicketID with who is assigned to it.

The query that shows the person being assigned the ticket is as follows:

```
SELECT  l.Login
FROM Ticket t1
LEFT JOIN
    TicketAssignments tass
ON
    tass.TicketID=t1.TicketID
LEFT JOIN
    Login l 
ON
    l.LoginID = tass.LoginID
```

However, I am missing 2 key things:

1)I need to display the TicketID as I have in the first example (with a group by ticketID)
2)I need to STUFF() the Login name so that it comes out comma seperated

Please stick with STUFF() I know at times it may not be the best way but I am just trying to use it in my code.

### edit

3 tables

```
Ticket 
------
TicketID
```

---

```
TicketAssignments
-----------------
TicketID
LoginID
```

---

```
Login
------
LoginID
```

---

```
Sample data:

Ticket
------
1
2
3


TicketAssignments
------------------
1   25
1   26
2   25
3   26
3   27

Login
-----
25 Joe
26 Jon
27 Jason
```

Result of what I want:

```
TicketID  Assignment
--------------------
    1, "Joe, Jon"
    2, "Joe"
    3, "Jon", "Jason"
```

That is Joe and Jon were assigned ticket 1
Joe is assigned ticket 2
Jon and Jason assigned to ticket 3

So the STUFF() just puts them together into one row per ticketid. I know this is not efficient, I am not asking for optimization right now...

As mentioned the query I have to get the ticket assignments it is:

SELECT  l.Login
    FROM Ticket t1
    LEFT JOIN
        TicketAssignments tass
    ON
        tass.TicketID=t1.TicketID
    LEFT JOIN
        Login l 
    ON
        l.LoginID = tass.LoginID

**However, I am missing 2 key things:
1)I need to display the TicketID as I have in the first example (with a group by ticketID)
2)I need to STUFF() the Login name so that it comes out comma seperated**

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results. Word problems are not fun.

Comment: @AaronBertrand ill edit..I take it you want example data from all 3 tables...

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Does the edit help?

Comment: Yes, thank you, much more useful than the word problem. Please see my answer.

Comment: [It is not STUFF that builds the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14373967/select-back-a-comma-delimited-list-grouped-by-an-id/14374392#14374392)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Nathan explained, `STUFF()` isn't actually performing any concatenation, it is simply removing the leading comma (which is better, IMHO, then having a trailing comma you have to remove by calculating the length of the output string and concatenating):

```
SELECT t.TicketID, Assignment = STUFF(
(
  SELECT N', "' + l.Name + '"'
    FROM dbo.Logins AS l
    INNER JOIN dbo.TicketAssignments AS ta
      ON l.LoginID = ta.LoginID
    WHERE ta.TicketID = t.TicketID
    FOR XML PATH(''), 
    TYPE).value(N'./text()[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, N'')
FROM dbo.Tickets AS t
ORDER BY t.TicketID;
```

Output:

| TicketID | Assignment |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "Joe", "Jon" |
| 2 | "Joe" |
| 3 | "Jon", "Jason" |

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=065a9cd02f4a8a966d2df4fe257f808f)

Note that on SQL Server 2017 and greater, you can use `STRING_AGG()` and this becomes a little easier:

```
SELECT t.TicketID, 
  Assignment = STRING_AGG(CONCAT('"', l.Name, '"'), ', ')
FROM dbo.Tickets AS t
INNER JOIN dbo.TicketAssignments AS ta
  ON t.TicketID = ta.TicketID
INNER JOIN dbo.Logins AS l
  ON ta.LoginID = l.LoginID
GROUP BY t.TicketID;
```

- Updated [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5b0d4614fc786b8f59f94938c530e030)

Answer (score 2):

`STUFF` is just removing the leading comma that results from the way you are concatenating the tags (or login.name as youre requesting).  The `FOR XML` clause is actually doing the work of concatenation.

See this example:

```
declare @Ticket table (TicketId int);
insert into @Ticket
    select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3;

declare @TicketAssignments table (TicketId int, LoginId int)
insert into @TicketAssignments
    select 1,25 union all
    select 1,26 union all
    select 2,25 union all
    select 3,26 union all
    select 3,27;

declare @Login table (LoginId int, Name varchar(10));
insert into @Login
    select 25, 'Joe' union all
    select 26, 'Jon' union all
    select 27, 'Jason';


select  ticketId,
        p.n,
        stuff(p.n, 1, 1, '')
from    @Ticket t
cross
apply   (   select  ',' + l.Name
            from    @TicketAssignments ta
            join    @Login l on ta.LoginId = l.LoginId
            where   ta.TicketId = t.TicketId
            for xml path('')
        )p(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following example shows how to apply stuff function on two columns.I have 3 tables in hierarchical order.
Job->storejob-> StorejobAssignment. The  tables in the hierarchy are associated with foreign key.
The primary key of table Job that is JobNo_pk will be present as a foreign key in store job table as Jobno_fk. But the JObno_fk is not available in StoreJobAssignment Table as it is in hierarchical order.

```
Select Top 10 j.JobNo_pk,
Stuff((select ','+ convert(varchar,StoreJobNo_pk) from Storejob
  where j.JobNo_PK=StoreJob.JobNo_FK  for XML path ('') ),1,1,'') as StorejobNO_pk,

 Stuff((select ','+ convert(varchar,StoreJobAssignmentNo_pk) from StorejobAssignment inner join StoreJob on StoreJob.StoreJobNo_PK=StoreJobAssignment.StoreJobNo_FK
  where StoreJob.Storejobno_pk=StoreJobAssignment.StorejobNo_fk for XML path ('') ),1,1,'') as Storejobassignmnet_pk   

  from job j
  inner join storejob    on j.jobno_pk=StoreJob.jobno_fk 
   inner join StorejobAssignment   on StoreJob.StoreJobno_pk=StoreJobAssignment.Storejobno_fk 
   group by Jobno_pk
```

[Click here to see the output of the above query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hojUM.png)