# T-SQL query that orders by a unique pattern or table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I can't seem to find any google or stackOverflow results on custom or unique tsql order by. I know there is a method to do this just not sure if it's possible in T-SQL. What I want to do is have a query that is returned in a certain unique order, according to warehouse locations.

I have a query that returns this -

The first thing is I would need order is the column [Location] and it's comma separated. So for example

FWD1, MAW1, D4Q5, O2G3B

would need to be ordered D4Q5, FWD1, MAW1, O2G3B 
but what if I wanted the Location to be in a unique order of O2G3b, FWD1, D4Q5, MAW1 for example
or any order based on a list or another table of locations

Then after the [Location] column is in order the entire query needs to be sorted in the same order

EDIT

How do you order by

```
item    location
-----------------
ITEM1        A
ITEM2        B
ITEM3        C
ITEM4        D
```

into any other order

```
item    location
-----------------
ITEM2        B
ITEM1        A
ITEM4        D
ITEM3        C
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand but this query and question hurts my brain.  Comma separate values in a table column?  your p3 aliased join seems weird... as it would seemingly rejoin all of the rows that were returned from p and p2.  What do you mean "what if i wanted the location to be in a unique order of..." I'm not following that statement at all.  Can you try to rephrase your question?  Or maybe other people will understand what you're asking /shrug

Comment: Do you seriously store comma delimited values in a single column? What is the point of joining to the table a third time for p3? I think you are asking how you can reorder your delimited list (stored as a varchar)? The best way to order this would be to normalize your table.

Comment: As does my brain. I've eliminated the query and added another example data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't fully answer your question without a bunch more details, but I think what you're looking for is to ORDER BY CASE, splitting up options using hardcoded groups (1, 2, etc), and then within each group you can also sort.

... ORDER BY CASE WHEN Location LIKE 'D4Q5%' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, Location.

If you're wanting to also create the comma separated list from the query, you'll want to use a CTE, [Select back a comma delimited list grouped by an ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14373967/select-back-a-comma-delimited-list-grouped-by-an-id) .

So if you also take the answer from that page

```
select ET1.EntryID,
       (
       select ', '+T.Name
       from Tags as T
         inner join EntryTag as ET2
           on T.TagID = ET2.TagID
       where ET1.EntryID = ET2.EntryID
       for xml path(''), type
       ).value('substring(text()[1], 3)', 'varchar(max)') as TagsCommaDelimited
from EntryTag as ET1
group by ET1.EntryID
```

and add an ORDER BY based on a column, I think it will basically accomplish what you're describing to sort by a column in a table

```
select ET1.EntryID,
       (
       select ', '+T.Name
       from Tags as T
         inner join EntryTag as ET2
           on T.TagID = ET2.TagID
       where ET1.EntryID = ET2.EntryID
       order by T.SortOrder
       for xml path(''), type
       ).value('substring(text()[1], 3)', 'varchar(max)') as TagsCommaDelimited
from EntryTag as ET1
group by ET1.EntryID
```

Comment: So if I have 5,327 locations I need 5,327 CASE WHEN LIKE statements.

Comment: No. How do you want to order them? If you want to use an order from another table, join to the other table and use that column in the ORDER BY. For any sort rules that you do not have a table defining the order, you will have to apply a CASE for.

Comment: I'm sorry I thought I mentioned it in the question but by table or a list of Locations. As mentioned there are 5300 locations as of this moment so each location would have a integer column that sets its ordinal value.