# tsql for xml string concat - How it works

Tags: sql, string, t-sql, aggregate-functions, string-concatenation

I have the following code which works well:

```
    STUFF(  ( 
                        select 
                            char(13)+'Item '+i.item+' : '--+char(13) +i.item_descr
                        from @itemlines i
                        where i.customer=main.customer
                        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                    ).value('.','varchar(max)')
                ,1,1, '')
```

What is the .value() thing? Something like a...select method? What does it do? Any reference links will be appreciated too!

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14374392/569436)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FOR XML` will return an XML datatype; the `.value(...,...)` pulls out the XML value and converts it to the datatype defined. In your case, everything in the root node ('.') converted to varchar(max)

For some blogs/links look at [Aaron Bertrand's post](https://sqlblog.org/2011/03/08/t-sql-tuesday-16-this-is-not-the-aggregate-youre-looking-for) or [Adam Machanic's](http://dataeducation.com/rowset-string-concatenation-which-method-is-best/) also watch out for `STRING_AGG` a new function in SQL2017

Answer (score 1):

You use `FOR XML PATH` to convert your table into XML. XML data are represented by a [XML data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/xml-transact-sql) in SQL Server and it is possible to process a list of different [methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/xml-data-type-methods) on this data type. One of these methods is a [value method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/value-method-xml-data-type) which has two arguments: XQuery and Data type. The method allows you to convert the data in XML into some other format (varchar in your case).