# What is exactly XML Path?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Can someone please explain with more detail what is actually `SELECT (STUFF SELECT...))FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(max)')`

From what I know:
`XmlPath('')`to **concatenate column data** into single row. 
`Stuff` is **used to remove the first ‘,’ after string concatenation.**

So what about `TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(max)')` use for ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Stuff and 'For Xml Path' work in Sql Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211506/how-stuff-and-for-xml-path-work-in-sql-server)

Comment: @KenY-N why it was possible if it can execute well on my database ??

Comment: I just want to ask and get the right information since I am new beginner.

Comment: @ Close voters: Don't know if you noticed, none of the *answers* in the "possible duplicate" explain why the TYPE directive is used when concatenating strings using FOR XML PATH. You guys ought to read the duplicate before smashing that close button. The many down votes are a little exaggerated as well IMO.

Comment: Have a look at [thls answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14374392/569436)

Comment: @MikaelEriksson That would indeed be a better candidate for a close vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So what about `TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(max)')` use for ?

The basics of `FOR XML PATH` you can find in a lot of questions/answers on SO (e.g. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35172160/243373), or [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31211506/243373)).

I'll focus on the `TYPE` directive. Consider the following T-SQL statement which concatenates the strings in the derived table `dt`:

```
SELECT
    [text()]=dt.x+';'
FROM
    (
        VALUES('text > blabla'),
              ('text < blabla'),
              ('f&m')
    ) AS dt(x)
FOR XML
    PATH('');
```

The result is:

```
text &gt; blabla;text &lt; blabla;f&amp;m;
```

You'll see that the `>`, `<` and `&` are substituted by the `&gt;`, `&lt;` and `&amp;`. The special characters (XML predefined entities) will be replaced.

You can disable this by specifying the [`TYPE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/type-directive-in-for-xml-queries) directive, which exports this as XML rather than text, then getting the string value from the XML. Getting this string value from the resulting XML, can be done by using the [`value()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/value-method-xml-data-type) method.

Using the `TYPE` directive in the above example:

```
SELECT 
    (
        SELECT
            [text()]=dt.x+';'
        FROM
            (
                VALUES('text > blabla'),
                      ('text < blabla'),
                      ('f&m')
            ) AS dt(x)
        FOR XML
            PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)');
```

You'd get:

```
text > blabla;text < blabla;f&m;
```

You can see that the XML special characters are not substituted.